# Not able to build repo on node

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs2, npm-install, node-gyp

[See image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n5PP.png)

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\adityarai\Documents\Questionnaire.UI\node_modules\deasync
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./build.js
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.15.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! (node:20828) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR! gyp info spawn c:\python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   
'C:\Users\adityarai\Documents\Questionnaire.UI\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'C:\Users\adityarai\Documents\Questionnaire.UI\node_modules\deasync\build\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   
'C:\Users\adityarai\Documents\Questionnaire.UI\node_modules\node-gyp\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\Users\adityarai\.node-gyp\16.15.0\include\node\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\Users\adityarai\.node-gyp\16.15.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\Users\adityarai\Documents\Questionnaire.UI\node_modules\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\Users\adityarai\.node-gyp\16.15.0\<(target_arch)\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\Users\adityarai\Documents\Questionnaire.UI\node_modules\deasync',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\Users\adityarai\Documents\Questionnaire.UI\node_modules\deasync\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\adityarai\Documents\Questionnaire.UI\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19042
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\adityarai\Documents\Questionnaire.UI\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\adityarai\Documents\Questionnaire.UI\node_modules\deasync
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.15.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed